# Yii parameterizing hostnames doesn't work with subdomains

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am following this "guide" [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#parameterizing-hostnames) and I am trying to get Yii to parse the subdomain from an url. However, this doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have in my `urlManager` in my main config file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'login' => 'site/login',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<subdomain:\w+>.lvho.st' => '<controller>/<action>',        <--this one
    ),
),
```

I am using "lvho.st" to access my localhost (I am using xampp) as some other people at stackoverflow have suggested it to test out subdomains on localhost without messing with the host file. However, when I try to access the "subdomain" by using:

```
$subdomain = $_GET['subdomain'];
```

PHP errors out and complains that the subdomain get parameter doesn't exist. The exact error message I am getting:

> Undefined index: subdomain

I have also tried enabling vhosts in apache and adding localhost to the windows host file, but that still doesn't work. Does vhosts have to be enabled for Yii to do this? The "guide" I refered to above does not mention needing vhost to be enabled.

Comment: For anyone curious, I gave up on trying to get Yii to parse the subdomain out. In the end, I just went with parsing the url manually with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your url to this

```
'http://<subdomain:\w+>.lvho.st/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

and in the corresponding action of the controller do not forget to set a parameter with name subdomain like

```
public function actionWhatever($subdomain)
{

echo $subdomain;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and all Yii gives me is "Error 400
Your request is invalid". I think this is Yii trying to say that it couldn't find the $subdomain variable. Does it matter that my yii stuff is located in a folder? In other words, the index.php would be found in "localhost/folder".

Comment: Do you know if I need vhost to be enabled in apache and also edit the host file? This was the second part of my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Handling parametrized sub domains is a bit tricky. You'll need to add in your protocol first (http:// or https://).

What gets tricky is if you need to support SSL on your main production system and non-SSL routes. If that is the case, you'll either need a lot of duplicate routes or to add the protocol on using a UrlManager class override